Pure rolling interrupted, does friction provide impulse?
When a ring is under pure rolling (no slipping and friction zero) on a horizontal rough surface and now another small ball hits it, can there be impulse due to friction? I feel that there should be impulse provided by friction but the solutions to the below question contradict it.

A thin ring of mass 2kg and radius 0.5 m is rolling without slipping on a horizontal plane with velocity 1m/s. A small ball of mass 0.1kg, moving with velocity 20 m/s in the opposite direction hits the ring at a height of 0.75m and goes vertically up with velocity 10m/s. Immediately after the collision


A. the ring has pure roation about its stationary CM.


B. the ring comes to a complete stop.


C. friction between the ring and the ground is to the left.


D. there is no friction between the ring and the ground.


The answer given is A and C. I understand how C is true but for A they have conserved linear momentum in horizontal direction. But what about impulse due to friction?
Link to solution

The impulse due to friction is much less than that due to the collision. Duplicate - Can linear momentum be conserved before and after collision in the presence of an external force?
